# How to ensure that the data is not retrieved and appended as a whole each time a new entry is added?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
func generateDataForRecents()  {
        if URLArrayStringThisSeason.count == 0 {
            self.activityIndicator2.isHidden = false
            self.activityIndicator2.startAnimating()
        }


        let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("palettes").queryLimited(toFirst: 100).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

                for each in snapDict as [String:AnyObject]{

                    let URL = each.value["URL"] as! String

                    self.URLArrayStringRecents.append(URL)
                    //print(self.URLArrayString.count)

                    //print(snapshot)

                    //let pictureTitle = each.value["title"] as! String
                    print(self.URLArrayStringRecents.count)
                }
            }

            self.whatsNewCollectionView?.reloadData() //Reloads data after the number and all the URLs are fetched
            self.activityIndicator2.stopAnimating()
            self.activityIndicator2.isHidden = true
        })


    }
```

The following code does a retrieval of data each time the function is called, or when a new data is added.

This is extremely useful when the app is first started up or closed and then restarted. However, when the app is running, whenever a new entry is added, the code seemed to run again and thus appending twice the amount of new data.

For example, when there are already 15 entries identified and then suddenly a new entry is added, the array of the URL would contain 15+16 thus amounting to a total of 31.

How do I make it such that the new data is added to the array instead of adding the entire snapshot in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do that by listening for `.childAdded` events, instead of listening for `.value`:

```
var query = databaseRef.child("palettes").queryLimited(toFirst: 100)
query.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    let URL = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath/: "URL").value as! String
    self.URLArrayStringRecents.append(URL)
}
```

Since you have a limit-query, adding a 101st item means that one item will be removed from the view. So you'll want to handle `.childRemoved` too:

```
query.observe(.childRemoved, with: { (snapshot) in 
    // TODO: remove the item from snapshot.key from the araay
})
```

I recommend that you spend some time in the relevant [documentation on handling child events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events) before continuing.

Comment: hmm correction: its let URL = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "URL").value as! String

and not childByAppendingPath. But thanks for the headsup!

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure about the syntax there. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below method. I have use this method not getting any duplicate entry.

```
func getallNotes()
{
    let firebaseNotesString: String = Firebase_notes.URL
    let firebaseNotes = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL(firebaseNotesString).child(email)
    firebaseNotes.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        if snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("Category").hasChildren()
        {
            let child = snapshot.children
            self.arrNotes = NSMutableArray()
            self.arrDictKeys = NSMutableArray()
            for itemsz in child
            {
                let childz = itemsz as! FIRDataSnapshot
                let AcqChildKey : String = childz.key

                if AcqChildKey == AcqIdGlobal
                {
                    if (childz.hasChildren() == true)
                    {
                        let dictChild = childz.value as! NSMutableDictionary
                        self.arrDictKeys = NSMutableArray(array: dictChild.allKeys)

                        for i in 0..<self.arrDictKeys.count
                        {
                            let _key = self.arrDictKeys.objectAtIndex(i).description()
                            print(_key)
                            let dictData : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: (dictChild.valueForKey(_key)?.mutableCopy())! as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
                            dictData.setObject(_key, forKey: "notesId")

                            self.arrNotes.addObject(dictData)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            self.tableviewNote.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the query for removed child,

```
query.observe(.childRemoved, with: { (snapshot) in

            print(snapshot)
            let URL = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "URL").value as! String
            self.URLArrayStringThisSeason = self.URLArrayStringThisSeason.filter() {$0 != URL}
            self.thisSeasonCollectionView.reloadData()
        })
```

it will obtain the URL of the removed child and then update the array accordingly.